# Extracting specific text between strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to extract specific lines from a .txt file, corresponding to 7 particular devices (0-6), and then operate on that data.

Here is an example:

From a very large file, I extract an event (here 169139), which contains information from 6 of the 7 devices (here just 1,2,3,4,5,6 because Device 0 has no data). For each such event, I don't know a priori, how many devices will give active as their output. It can be all, it can be none, or it can be some.

```
=== 169139 ===
Start: 4.80374e+19
End:   4.80374e+19
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
--- 2 ---
Pix 11, 31
Pix 12, 31
--- 3 ---
Pix 17, 53
Pix 16, 53
Pix 16, 54
--- 4 ---
Pix 44, 64
--- 5 ---
Pix 49, 133
Pix 48, 133
--- 6 ---
Pix 109, 143
Pix 108, 143
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144
```

The events are easily iterable and I can select the whole information on the screen until the next one (here, the next line from the .txt would be === 169140 ===).

I am able to extract information from a particular device using the following code:

```
def start_stop_plane (list, dev):
    start_reading = [i for i in range(len(list)) if list[i] == "--- " + str(dev) + " ---"][0]
    stop_reading = [i for i in range(len(list)) if list[i] == "--- " + str(int(dev)+1) + " ---"][0]
    return list[start_reading:stop_reading]
```

Here, **list** is the first code comment (the full event). It is a list produced in a similar manner to the code above, exchanging **---** with **===** string occurrences (ie, the flag between events).

My problem: This works for everything from 0 to 5. For 6 it crashes because there is no `int(dev)+1`. I tried putting an `or` in the `stop_reading` to identify an occurrence of `===` but it did not work.

In this case, How can I signal the end of the list and make sure I don't lose any device?

Comment: The variable `dev` seems to be defined nowhere in your code. I think you want to replace `plane` with `dev`.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke The function actually takes list and dev as input :) That plane was some old code remnants.

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare your "--- plane ---" marker and let python find it for you using basic functions such as `in` and `.index`.

To get the subset of data lines up to the next marker, you could use `takewhile` from itertools:

```
data="""=== 169139 ===
Start: 4.80374e+19
End:   4.80374e+19
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
--- 2 ---
Pix 11, 31
Pix 12, 31
--- 3 ---
Pix 17, 53
Pix 16, 53
Pix 16, 54
--- 4 ---
Pix 44, 64
--- 5 ---
Pix 49, 133
Pix 48, 133
--- 6 ---
Pix 109, 143
Pix 108, 143
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144""".split("\n")

from itertools import takewhile
def planeData(data,plane):
    marker = f"--- {plane} ---"
    if marker not in data: return []
    start = data.index(marker)+1
    return list(takewhile(lambda d:not d.startswith("---"),data[start:]))
```

output:

```
for line in planeData(data,0): print(line)
# nothing printed

for line in planeData(data,5): print(line)
# Pix 49, 133
# Pix 48, 133

for line in planeData(data,6): print(line)
# Pix 49, 133
# Pix 48, 133
# Pix 109, 143
# Pix 108, 143
# Pix 108, 144 
# Pix 109, 144
```

Comment: Hi Alain! Thank you for replying to this!
I cannot manage to get the code working, as it complains that the list is non callable in the return of the function. Taking a set, instead of a list works, but it brings some more complications. How did you manage to have it working?

Comment: Later edit: The problem with list not being callable seems to only be related to Jupyter Notebooks. No such issue running python from the shell.

Comment: I could be due to a difference of version of Python itself. The format strings `f"--- {plane} ---"` appeared in Python 3 and are not supported by Python 2.x

Comment: You are right. It was a versioning issue. 
There is one thing I did not manage to compute. Suppose another event `=== abc ===` is contained in the file, right after the last line from the data above. 

Example:
```data="""=== 169139 ===
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
--- 6 ---
Pix 108, 144
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144
=== 169140 ===
Start: 4.80374e+19
End:   4.80374e+19""".split("\n")
```
The takewhile will not stop if a `===` is detected, only if another `---` appears. How can I signal the end of a event in that case?

Comment: You could replace `not d.startswith("---")` with `not d.replace("=","-").startswith("---")` or with `d[:3] not in ["---","==="]`

Comment: Many thanks, Alain! Working as intended! Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could use string [Index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm)

**Code**

```
def start_stop_dev(lst, dev):
    " Assume you meant dev rather than plane "
    try:
      start_reading = lst.index("--- " + str(dev) + " ---")
    except:
      return ""   # No device

    try:
      stop_reading = lst.index("--- " + str(dev+1) + " ---") - 1
    except:
      stop_reading = len(lst)

    if start_reading:
        return lst[start_reading:stop_reading]
    else:
      return None  # not really possible since return "" earlier
```

**Test**

```
lst= """=== 169139 ===
Start: 4.80374e+19
End:   4.80374e+19
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
--- 2 ---
Pix 11, 31
Pix 12, 31
--- 3 ---
Pix 17, 53
Pix 16, 53
Pix 16, 54
--- 4 ---
Pix 44, 64
--- 5 ---
Pix 49, 133
Pix 48, 133
--- 6 ---
Pix 109, 143
Pix 108, 143
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144"""

# Retrieve and print data for each device
print('----------------Individual Device String Info-------------')
for dev in range(7):
  print(f'device {dev}\n{start_stop_dev(lst, dev)}')

print('----------------Splits of String Info----------------------')
for dev in range(7):
  dev_lst = start_stop_dev(lst,dev).split("\n")
  print(f'dev {dev}: {dev_lst}')
```

**Output**
----------------Individual Device String Info-------------

```
device 0

device 1
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
device 2
--- 2 ---
Pix 11, 31
Pix 12, 31
device 3
--- 3 ---
Pix 17, 53
Pix 16, 53
Pix 16, 54
device 4
--- 4 ---
Pix 44, 64
device 5
--- 5 ---
Pix 49, 133
Pix 48, 133
device 6
--- 6 ---
Pix 109, 143
Pix 108, 143
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144
----------------Splits of String Info----------------------
dev 0: ['']
dev 1: ['--- 1 ---', 'Pix 9, 66']
dev 2: ['--- 2 ---', 'Pix 11, 31', 'Pix 12, 31']
dev 3: ['--- 3 ---', 'Pix 17, 53', 'Pix 16, 53', 'Pix 16, 54']
dev 4: ['--- 4 ---', 'Pix 44, 64']
dev 5: ['--- 5 ---', 'Pix 49, 133', 'Pix 48, 133']
dev 6: ['--- 6 ---', 'Pix 109, 143', 'Pix 108, 143', 'Pix 108, 144 ', 'Pix 109, 144']
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer!
I noticed I need `lst[start_reading:stop_reading-1]`, to get rid of an extra empty line.
The reason I get this, is because I use `start_stop_dev(lst,1).split('\n')` to get a list, in order to further work on those values inside. This of course, does not work for cases with no entries, like 0 here. 
Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @nyw--check code update.  `lst[start_reading:stop_reading-1]` isn't quite correct since it wouldn't work on the last device (i.e. drops 4 in 144), but corrected code should handle this.  I show the results for `lst[start_reading:stop_reading])` and for lst[start_reading:stop_reading]).split('\n').  I also enumerate from device 0 to 7 to show the output for missing devices.

Comment: This works great now! I am now trying different test cases. Many thanks!