# Assigning events to pre-defined shapes

Tags: python, matrix, cluster-analysis, pixel

My questions comes following what has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428166/extracting-specific-text-between-strings) and the advice I've been given there.

I get data from seven devices (each, an XY matrix of responsive pixel sensors; think of a CCD camera). The dimensions of each device is X:1024 pixels, Y:512 pixels. The data is structured into separate events (i.e., timestamped), where a number of such pixels are active per event. The XY position of each pixel is represented by the two numbers following the `Pix` keyword in each device.

An example of such an event, where only 6 of the 7 devices have active pixels:

```
=== 169139 ===
Start: 4.80374e+19
End:   4.80374e+19
--- 1 ---
Pix 9, 66
--- 2 ---
Pix 11, 31
Pix 12, 31
--- 3 ---
Pix 17, 53
Pix 16, 53
Pix 16, 54
--- 4 ---
Pix 44, 64
--- 5 ---
Pix 49, 133
Pix 48, 133
--- 6 ---
Pix 109, 143
Pix 108, 143
Pix 108, 144 
Pix 109, 144
```

I am now able to separate and plot for each of the 6 devices a 2D histogram showing where and which pixels were active thanks to the previous mentioned question in the forum.

I do not know beforehand how many planes will be active in each event, which pixels will be active and how many in a device.

What I would like to do next, would be to make a "**frequency of occurrence**" of different shapes of these pixels per plane. If a bunch of neighboring pixels are active, they are called a cluster. An example of such a classification:

[image: Different active pixel shapes]

As such, for the event example given above, one will find:

- 2 occurrences of shape ID 0 (devices 1 and 4)
- 2 occurrences of shape ID 1 (devices 2 and 5)
- 1 occurrence of shape ID 6 (device 3)
- 1 occurrence of shape ID 12 (device 6)

A first classification would be based on the number of lines each device has. This would be a good indication of the number of active pixels per device (case not taken into account: if two regions of the same device have a active pixels firing at the same event).

For one line in an event (meaning one pixel active), I could directly classify it into the number 0 category.
For two lines, I could look to the left/right (or top/bottom) neighboring pixel and check if it is active and classify it as event 1 (or 2).

For the case of 3 pixels, I am a bit unsure how to check. Basically, I would take the first value of the `Pix` occurrence of that device, but how would I know which of 3 active pixels it is?

Also, how can I "classify" events in Python? I am thinking of a dictionary of shapes. And some function checks to assign a certain occurrence to such a shape. How is this implemented in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a dictionary of occurences, indeed.

A straight forward solution is:

1. Create a dictionary of NxN matrices of 0s and 1s. Generate all these possible matrices iteratively.
   e.g. N=3

[00,00] [10,00] [01,00] [00,10] [00,01] [11,00] ... [ 11,11]

2. Whenever a new event comes, normalize your pixel matrix and match it with the one on the dictionary. Increase the counter for it.
   D(001 000 000) ++

Optionally, to optimize this, don’t initialize the dictionary. Just add a new entry if it doesn’t exist and increment the counter.

3. Then, if you don’t care about the pixel positions and you’re only about the shapes, process the dictionary.

Create another dictionary of shapes, such as:
Point, 2-line, 2-column, 3-line, 3-column, T, reverse T, L, reverse L and so on.

This way you can go closer and closer towards the solution and identify the points which need to remain abstract or not.

I know it’s not a concrete solution but it might bring you closer to what you want.

Comment: Ok, I might have gotten a bit into this, following your suggestion.
I can isolate and cluster the pixels. For each such cluster I can calculate the number of pixels, the column width and row width.
This lets me to have rough categories. 

There are a few cases where I cannot extend this and would love some input: **how can I designate a different category for the objects with 3 pixels active, 2 rows and 2 columns (ie : cluster IDs 3,4,6,7 from the figure above)?**
This is of course extended to 4 active pixels and pairs of row-column of 2-3 or 3-2.